# How to avoid caching HTTP requests on python? (aiohttp)

Tags: python, http, python-requests, aiohttp

I'm running a project on replit, and I do some http requests (using aiohttp) to some rest api endpoint. The problem is it keeps returning an old version of the response. When I try to access the same rest api endpoint on a browser or curl, the response have already changed/updated. But when I run my code within replit, the responses are still old from the previous request.

Tried running the request using python shell (aiohttp and requests) within the repl and still getting the same problem, but when I use curl it's fine.

I already tried cached-control/pragma/expires on headers, but still no luck.

Comment: Just for testing: try changing the `User-Agent` header to random strings between requests and make sure, that aiohttp doesn’t send any cookies. If this fixes the problem, the cache is on the server or in a proxy in between. We’ve seen Django instances cache pages in memcached for one browser and delivering fresh ones for another browser on the same machine. If this is the case, you must change anything in your request to get a fresh response.

Comment: @Boldewyn I already tried something like that, I added timestamp as query param, ?timestamp=12345..., using the current timestamp so it's always different. Yeah, I'm accessing a proxy server that caches response to avoid spam (TTL set to 4 hours), but Idk, my browser/curl already returns a different cached response, but still my code sees an older one.

Answer (score 1):

use this header when sending request

```
  headers = {
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
  }

session.get(url , headers=headers)
```